# is there any difference between outside memo and in function memo?

Tags: react-native, expo

are both methods working fine with memo or should my Item be outside ?

Outside:

```js
function isEqual(prev: IMyOrders, next: IMyOrders) {
  if(prev.name=== next.name) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

const Item = ({
  name,
  t
}: { name: string; t: any; }) => {
  return (
    <Pressable style={s.item}>
       <Text style={s.product_name}>Ordered Date: { t('profile.logged.reviews.created_at', { date: order_date }) }</Text>
    </Pressable>
    )
  };

const MEMO_ITEM = memo(Item, isEqual);

## MEMO END ##

const SettingsMyOrders = () => {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  const renderItem: ListRenderItem<IMyOrders> = ({ item }) => (
    <MEMO_ITEM 
      {...item}
      t={t}
    />
  );

  return (
     <FlashList 
       data={data}
       keyExtractor={(item, i) => item.name.toString()}
       renderItem={renderItem}
       estimatedItemSize={280.7}
     />
  )
}
```

Without outside:

```js
function isEqual(prev: IMyOrders, next: IMyOrders) {
  if(prev.name=== next.name) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

## MEMO END ##

const SettingsMyOrders = () => {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  const renderItem: ListRenderItem<IMyOrders> = memo(({ item }) => (
    <Pressable style={s.item}>
       <Text style={s.product_name}>Ordered Date: { t('profile.logged.reviews.created_at', { date: order_date }) }</Text>
    </Pressable>
  ), isEqual);

  return (
     <FlashList 
       data={data}
       keyExtractor={(item, i) => item.name.toString()}
       renderItem={renderItem}
       estimatedItemSize={280.7}
     />
  )
}
```

Can anyone explain me if this both works correctly fine with memoized ?

I am very thankful for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, you will create a new memoization function on each render, so you need to use outside the method.